# Позиционирование div по центру экрана

Tags: css, вёрстка, html

Помогите пожалуйста! Буду очень признателен!

Мне нужно расположить три/ четыре div в ряд так, что бы при изменении ширины браузера divы не изменяли размер, а выстраивались один за другим, но при этом всегда находились по центру.

divы должны всегда занимать всю ширину родительского дива, который тянется вместе с браузером.

В итоге должно получиться что-то типа этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>






    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper {
        position: inherit;
            margin: 0 auto;


        }
        .section {
            border:solid 1px #999;
            float:left;
            height:250px;
            margin-left:10px;
            width:350px;
            margin-top: 15px;
        }
        #wrapper div:first-child {
            margin-left:10px;
        }
    </style>





</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: разместите ваши div'ы ещё в один контейнер, а его спозиционируйте по центру

Comment: Так проблема не решается. Это не ответ на мой вопрос. В любому случае, спасибо, что откликнулись.

Comment: Автор, может сделайте тогда картинки со всеми состояниями и перефразируйте вопрос. По описанию не понятно должны дивы быть фиксированной ширины или "должны всегда занимать всю ширину родительского дива, который тянется вместе с браузером". итд

Comment: Cпасибо всем участникам. Проблему решил.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/68559)

Answer (score 1):

А может вам нужно это. При изменении ширины родительского div-а внутренние тоже изменяются

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center; /* выравниваем по горизонтали */
  vertical-align: middle; /* выравниваем по вертикали */
  }

.section {
width: 32%;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center; /* выравниваем по горизонтали */
  vertical-align: middle; /* выравниваем по вертикали */
  }

.section {
width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы же видите, что у вас они по левому краю страницы, и при уменьшении они не встают друг под дружку. При уменьшении должны оставаться так же по центру страницы )

Comment: для наглядности поправил код, блоки по центру wrapper и если уменьшить его ширину то блоки будут тоже по центру

Comment: Даже не знаю, это шутка? :( https://fiddle.jshell.net/ Как же они по центру то? http://prntscr.com/afcx78

Comment: просто в моем коде стоит фиксированная ширина вам нужно поставить относительную вот здесь стоит относительная https://fiddle.jshell.net/x2bxc0hb/2/

Answer (score 0):

Вот так что-ли?

```css
#wrapper {
  position: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.section {
  border: solid 1px #999;
/*   float: left; */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#wrapper div:first-child {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: нет. ни так... абсолютно.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 550px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #44a527;
}
.section {
  border: solid 1px #999;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```